# row operation proof for elementary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, matrix-decomposition

> **Theorem:** If the matrix $\bar{A}$ is the result of applying a row operation $R$ to the matrix $A$, and if $E$ is the matrix that results from applying $R$ to the identity matrix $I$, then $\bar{A}=EA$

Proof:

The author provides a proof for which I am unclear and uncomfortable.

Suppose the $R$ is the operation of adding $c$ times row $s$ in $A$ onto row $r$ for $r \neq  s$. The action of $R$ on the $n \times n$ identity matrix produces the elementary matrix $E$ with these entries:

$$E_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+c \delta_{ir} \delta_{sj}$$

I am unable to understand the existence of $\delta_{ir}$ and why the row r appears as a column index.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\delta_{ir}=1$ if and only if $i=r$. You want to add something to the $i$th row only if it is the $r$th row.

Comment: Is having the column index even necessary in this proof? It causes more confusion.

Comment: It's not column index, $\delta_{ij}$ is simply the Kronecker delta which equals $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. The author means that you add $c$ only if $i=r$ and $s=j$. And that's correct because if we are not in row $r$ then we shouldn't add anything, and if we are not in column $s$ then we will just add $0$, because then the $(s,j)$ entry of the identity matrix is $0$. I agree he wrote it in a confusing way though.

Comment: The index j refers to the column index. Let me study it - indeed confusing way to state a proof...

Comment: Yes, when he writes $E_{ij}$ he means $j$ is the column index. In $\delta_{ij}$ he simply means the Kronecker delta. I think it would be better if he simply explained it in words like I did in the previous comment instead of writing this formula.